# VueJs how to pass Parent prop to slot component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

[DEMO](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

As you can see below Parent component is `FancyList` which is `const item = ref(null)` defined in its script. which needs to be passed to any component which is in its slot

// root

```
<script setup>
import FancyList from './FancyList.vue'
import ItemComp from './ItemComp.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <FancyList api-url="url" :per-page="10">
    <template v-slot:top #item="item">
      <ItemComp :item="item" />
    </template>
  </FancyList>
</template>

<style scoped>
.meta {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #42b883;
}
</style>
```

**FancyList vue component**

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['api-url', 'per-page'])

const item = ref(null)

// mock remote data fetching
setTimeout(() => {
  item.value = document.querySelector('body')
}, 1000)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  <h1>FancyList</h1>
  <slot name="top" v-bind="item" />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, #42d392 25%, #647eff);
  }
  li {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the expected behavior of the code is, but you probably want to change this line

```
<template v-slot:top #item="item">
```

to

```
<template v-slot:top="item">
```

or just

```
<template #top="item">
```

Comment: thanks this worked. Im actually trying to pass ref of Parent to the component. such that I this child component will manipulate Parent styling, this is needed so I can add/remove style components.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @foURP answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77278756/942317):
I had to do this additionally to get the slots props working:

```
<script>
const item = computed<HTMLElement | null>(() =>
  document.querySelector('[data-testid="card"]'),
)

const slotProps = { item }
<script>
<template>
...
          <slot
            name="top"
            v-bind="slotProps"
          />
...
</template>
```

and now where you want to use it, pass it like this:

```js
         <FancyList>
          <template #top="{parent}">
            <ContentVisibleOnHover :parent="parent">
              <FavoriteButton :isFavorite="false" />
            </ContentVisibleOnHover>
          </template>
...
```